# Javascript widget performance: fetching static HTML/JS files -versus- DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript

I'm building an JS embeddable widget.

The HTML/CSS is static, won't change much and it's around 10 KB.

What's the fastest way to load it?

(A) DOM manipulation, e.g.

```
var node = document.createElement("LI");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
node.appendChild(textnode); 
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(node);  
// repeat the above for all other HTML elements here
```

(B) Fetch + innerHTML, e.g.

```
const response = await fetch('allTheHTML.html', {
        method: 'GET', 
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' }
    });
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = response.text()
```

Or ...some other method?

Comment: An AJAX request will almost certainly take longer.

Comment: The best way of determining the fastest method is always to test and measure in your specific environment, under the specific loads you expect. But, I/O is a frequent bottleneck...